# Github Actions - detect concurrency using multiple unique names?

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible with github actions to use multiple concurrency unique names to detect that job of same type is already running, to prevent clashes?

For example I have deployment workflow, where you can specify whether you want to deploy to single specific host or to whole hosts group.

If only deploying to specifc host at a time, then its easy, as you can do something like:

`concurrency: deploying_to_${{ inputs.host }}`

But what if there is already deployment to hosts group? For example I am deploying to Group X consisting of Hosts A, B, C. And then someone decided to deploy to just host `A`.

So now we have `deploying_to_X` and `deploying_to_A`, which of course will be treated as distinct deployments.

What I mean, if it would be something like:

```yaml
concurrency:
   group: deploying_to_A
   parent_group: deploying_to_X
```

So if there is another deployment that has `group` called `deploying_to_X`, `deploying_to_A` would need to wait instead of being run immediately.

Reading documentation I did not find that it is possible, but maybe there is some work around?

Comment: From what I understand reading the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#example-using-a-fallback-value), a syntax like this `parent_group` field doesn't exist. However, it seems you can use some kind of expressions for the `group`. Something like: `group: ${{ deploying_to_A || deploying_to_X }}`

Comment: @GuiFalourd not sure that expression would help. As I understand it would just fallback to `deploying_to_X` if `deploying_to_A` could not be defined. But when I am deploying to A, I want to specify that. And when I deploy to Host group and includes `A` host, it should somehow know that its being deployed already, meaning it should wait or vise versa.

Comment: In the example I shared, wouldn't a new workflow being queued if there is already a workflow in the `deploying_to_A` group, or in the `deploying_to_X` group, running? I understand that what you want is to prevent a new deployment if there is already one in the host running, right?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want. Regarding that example, I don't think so. At least according to documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-fallback-value what it means, is it would just evaluate to fallback value when workflow/job is run. So if `deploying_to_X` is to be run, it would always evaluate to that, if `A` is undefined. So that new deployment would actually know nothing that `A` is already being deployed. I think its just to handle different triggers/events.

Comment: In other words it would still check one or the other. But in this case, it should check both before knowing if need to wait or deploy.

Comment: You may not be able to achieve what you want by using `concurrency` alone in that case. A workaround could be to create a `check` job that would be a premisse for the other jobs to run, and that would generate an output `true` or `false` if the rest of the workflow should run or not.